# Android, how to replace slashes in path

Tags: android

i have an image path : `"UploadFile\\/UserProfile\\/Female.jpg"`. How to replace `"\\/"` with `"/"`?
i have tried :

1. `replaceAll("\\/","/")`
2. `replaceAll("\\\\/","/")`

Code:

```
adapter_profilepic = objUser.getProfilePicture().replaceAll("\\/","/");
```

Comment: m getting a json response and storing all details in an object of User class, adapter_profilepic = objUser.getProfilePicture().replaceAll("\\/","/");

Answer (score 1):

[This works](http://ideone.com/GjrfYU) :

```
String src = "UploadFile\\/UserProfile\\/Female.jpg";
src = src.replaceAll("\\\\/","/");
System.out.println(src);
```

output:

```
UploadFile/UserProfile/Female.jpg
```

You said you tried it, but check it again.

Comment: actually i tried, once i run the output i get the image in emulator, when i run it again image disappears

Answer (score 0):

According [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) your string is used as `regular expression`. Why you don't using [replace](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29):

```
String adapter_profilepic = objUser.getProfilePicture().replace("\\\\/","/");
```

Comment: thnks but i think der's some other problem. my image disappers when i run it 2nd time in emulator

Comment: If you found right answer you should accept it and ask new question. You should read more in [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)